# I want to use username as a page address in url

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

For example I want to access username page directly like this:

```
mysite.com/username
```

to redirect to my SiteController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several solutions, but i think there's a more Yii-like way to do it.

First off you need the default .htacces-file in your web folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then you need the urlManager in either your common/config/main or your frontend/common/main.

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<username:\w+>' => 'site/profile'  // This will handle your usernames
        ],
    ],
],
```

And finally a actionProfile($username) in your site controller

```
public function actionProfile($username) {
    $model = \common\models\User::find()->where(['username' => $username])->one();
    die($model->username);
}
```

You might also find these links useful:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html

**Edit:**
Oh, wait! You want all the site/actions to work on yoururl.com/actions ?

Then you'll need

```
'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<alias:index|all|your|actions|here>' => 'site/<alias>',
        ],
    ],
```

Or:

```
'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<action:\w+' => 'site/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: thanks, it's worked when i used   site.com/profile/username , but i want to have site.com/username

Comment: Okey, so the original url is /site/profile/username?

Comment: Yes, follow the steps before "Edit"

Comment: I tried it, it works. `'<username:\w+>' => 'site/profile'` in your urlManager, and actionProfile in siteController

Comment: That is wired, cus i set it up on my own computer

Comment: please make an example for url address.

Comment: If you follow my instructions exactly (before the Edit section) you'll be able to enter www.myurl.com/admin f.ex

Comment: I solved, i used this 'restaurant/<action:\w+>/' => 'site/<action>' . thanks Jorgen

Answer (score 2):

It is named [URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting) and is provided by the server through some server module. For example `mod_rewrite` in apache.

Once configured, it will get needed parameters from the URL and send them to your script in an usual manner, through the QUERY_STRING environment variable.

You should not change your php code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /SiteControllet.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will actually work as
    Sitecontroller.php?username=somename
You'll need to use user.php to find data.

First of course you'll need to enable 
    mod_rewrite 
in the apache configuration.

Umcomment this line in the config file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.s
```

Remember, the .htaccess should be in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

create a file named '.htaccess' and write the following in the file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{filename} !-d
RewriteCond %{filename} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

hope it helps ! 
:D
or for more advanced options you may search for "url-rewriting" .

P.S. i am not a native english speaker.

Comment: Asking for upvoting is lame. Please take care of that.